# So many problems with my bibliography!

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, page-numbering

I'm sorry because I have yet more questions but you all seem to understand LaTeX way better than me! So I have a couple of problems with my bibliography - it's nothing major but it is bugging me.

1 - The page number on the first page of the bibliography is centred bottom whereas the rest of the pages are at the right-hand bottom. In my other chapters, I have managed to get around this by including \thispagestyle{style2} for the first page and then \pagestyle{style1} for the remainder of the pages (this may be superfluous but it's what I found worked in order to get the first page to have no header and a right-hand bottom number and the rest of the pages with a header and a right-hand bottom number). However, this won't work on the bibliography because it isn't classified as a chapter - so does anyone have any ideas what I can do? [[image: Problem Citation]]

This is my pre-amble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{style1}
{\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\rfoot{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{style2}
{\fancyhf{} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

In the reference.bib file:

```
@article{Maes2019Taxonomy2018,
    title = {{Taxonomy of the order Bunyavirales: second update 2018}},
    year = {2019},
    journal = {Archives of Virology},
    author = {Maes, Piet and Adkins, Scott and Alkhovsky, Sergey V. and Av{\v{s}}i{\v{c}}-{\v{Z}}upanc, Tatjana and Ballinger, Matthew J. and Bente, Dennis A. and Beer, Martin and Bergeron, Éric and Blair, Carol D. and Briese, Thomas and Buchmeier, Michael J. and Burt, Felicity J. and Calisher, Charles H. and Charrel, Rémi N. and Choi, Il Ryong and Clegg, J. Christopher S. and de la Torre, Juan Carlos and de Lamballerie, Xavier and DeRisi, Joseph L. and Digiaro, Michele and Drebot, Mike and Ebihara, Hideki and Elbeaino, Toufic and Erg{\"{u}}nay, Koray and Fulhorst, Charles F. and Garrison, Aura R. and G{\={a}}o, George Fú and Gonzalez, Jean-Paul J. and Groschup, Martin H. and G{\"{u}}nther, Stephan and Haenni, Anne-Lise and Hall, Roy A. and Hewson, Roger and Hughes, Holly R. and Jain, Rakesh K. and Jonson, Miranda Gilda and Junglen, Sandra and Klempa, Boris and Klingstr{\"{o}}m, Jonas and Kormelink, Richard and Lambert, Amy J. and Langevin, Stanley A. and Lukashevich, Igor S. and Marklewitz, Marco and Martelli, Giovanni P. and Mielke-Ehret, Nicole and Mirazimi, Ali and M{\"{u}}hlbach, Hans-Peter and Naidu, Rayapati and Nunes, Márcio Roberto Teixeira and Palacios, Gustavo and Papa, Anna and Paw{\c{e}}ska, Janusz T. and Peters, Clarence J. and Plyusnin, Alexander and Radoshitzky, Sheli R. and Resende, Renato O. and Romanowski, Víctor and Sall, Amadou Alpha and Salvato, Maria S. and Sasaya, Takahide and Schmaljohn, Connie and Sh{\'{i}}, Xiǎohóng and Shirako, Yukio and Simmonds, Peter and Sironi, Manuela and Song, Jin-Won and Spengler, Jessica R. and Stenglein, Mark D. and Tesh, Robert B. and Turina, Massimo and W{\`{e}}i, Tàiyún and Whitfield, Anna E. and Yeh, Shyi-Dong and Zerbini, F. Murilo and Zhang, Yong-Zhen and Zhou, Xueping and Kuhn, Jens H.},
    number = {3},
    month = {3},
    pages = {927--941},
    volume = {164},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s00705-018-04127-3},
    isbn = {2163684814},
    doi = {10.1007/s00705-018-04127-3},
    issn = {0304-8608},
    pmid = {30663021}
}
```

2 - I keep getting this error message because there's too many authors in two of the references. I'm using natbib because the agsm bibliography style gives me the closest to the referencing style that I need.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Error message:

```
BibTeX you've exceeded 250, the entry-string-size, for entry Maes2018Taxonomy2018b
```

3 - Finally this one really doesn't matter, but I would prefer the Bibliography to be called References instead but I don't know how to change it. I've included the entire pre-amble of my report in case you need to see it?

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4 paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1ED3}{\`{\^{o}}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}

\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=20mm,bottom=20mm,outer=20mm,inner=40mm}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\rhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{style1}
{\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\rfoot{\thepage}}

\fancypagestyle{style2}
{\fancyhf{} 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{/Figures/}
 \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-10pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}

\DeclareCaptionJustification{nohyphen}{\hyphenpenalty=100000}
\captionsetup{justification=nohyphen}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Sorry for so many questions (and probably too much information) but I am still getting to grips with LaTeX... I'd gladly accept any suggestion of improvements too :)

Thanks, 
Amelia

Comment: How does the entry bibtex is complaining about look like?

Comment: I've (hopefully) added a screenshot of the problem reference

Comment: In your input, what *you* typed in.

Comment: I haven't typed anything in - I imported it from Mendeley... But this is what is in the reference.bib file (I've edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned your `.tex` snippets for the header and footer and made new  additions. Below is the full MWE which should solve your queries.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1ED3}{\`{\^{o}}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}

\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage[top=20mm, bottom=20mm, outer=20mm, inner=40mm]{geometry}
% \newgeometry{top=20mm,bottom=20mm,outer=20mm,inner=40mm}


\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

%------------------HEADERS & FOOTERS (cleaned + new addition)-----------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
% 
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

%---------------------------------------
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    %
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
% --------------------------------------------

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-10pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}
% 
% 
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
% 
% 
\DeclareCaptionJustification{nohyphen}{\hyphenpenalty=100000}
\captionsetup{justification=nohyphen}
% 
% 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{har2nat} 
% % \bibliographystyle{agsm}  % used below 

%-----------
\usepackage{lipsum} % to add random texts
%-------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Right-hand bottom Page Number}
\lipsum[1-3]  

\cite{Maes2019Taxonomy2018, Greener2020, M19, Na2020}

More \cite{green20} % added few extra references to show 2 (two) pages of References

% ---------------New addition-------------------

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} %<---this would change the name 'Bibliography' to 'References'


\bibliographystyle{agsm} %
\bibliography{biblio} % reference bib file


\end{document}
```

Save the references in a file `biblio.bib`. To note, in the `bib` file, I have added few extra references, apart from the one you have provided, to show 2 (two) pages of References.

```
@Article{Maes2019Taxonomy2018,
author={Maes, Piet and Adkins, Scott and Alkhovsky, Sergey V. and Av{\v{s}}i{\v{c}}-{\v{Z}}upanc, Tatjana
and Ballinger, Matthew J. and Bente, Dennis A. and Beer, Martin and Bergeron, {\'E}ric and Blair, Carol D. and Briese, Thomas and Buchmeier, Michael J. and Burt, Felicity J. and Calisher, Charles H. and Charrel, R{\'e}mi N. and Choi, Il Ryong and Clegg, J. Christopher S. and de la Torre, Juan Carlos and de Lamballerie, Xavier and DeRisi, Joseph L. and Digiaro, Michele and Drebot, Mike and Ebihara, Hideki and Elbeaino, Toufic and Erg{\"u}nay, Koray and Fulhorst, Charles F. and Garrison, Aura R. and G{\={a}}o, George F{\'u} and Gonzalez, Jean-Paul J. and Groschup, Martin H. and G{\"u}nther, Stephan and Haenni, Anne-Lise and Hall, Roy A. and Hewson, Roger and Hughes, Holly R. and Jain, Rakesh K. and Jonson, Miranda Gilda and Junglen, Sandra and Klempa, Boris and Klingstr{\"o}m, Jonas and Kormelink, Richard and Lambert, Amy J. and Langevin, Stanley A. and Lukashevich, Igor S. and Marklewitz, Marco and Martelli, Giovanni P. and Mielke-Ehret, Nicole and Mirazimi, Ali and M{\"u}hlbach, Hans-Peter and Naidu, Rayapati and Nunes, M{\'a}rcio Roberto Teixeira and Palacios, Gustavo and Papa, Anna and Paw{\k{e}}ska, Janusz T. and Peters, Clarence J. and Plyusnin, Alexander and Radoshitzky, Sheli R. and Resende, Renato O. and Romanowski, V{\'i}ctor and Sall, Amadou Alpha and Salvato, Maria S. and Sasaya, Takahide and Schmaljohn, Connie and Sh{\'i}, Xi{\v{a}}oh{\'o}ng and Shirako, Yukio and Simmonds, Peter and Sironi, Manuela and Song, Jin-Won and Spengler, Jessica R. and Stenglein, Mark D. and Tesh, Robert B. and Turina, Massimo and W{\`e}i, T{\`a}iy{\'u}n and Whitfield, Anna E. and Yeh, Shyi-Dong and Zerbini, F. Murilo and Zhang, Yong-Zhen and Zhou, Xueping and Kuhn, Jens H.},
title={Taxonomy of the order Bunyavirales: second update 2018},
journal={Archives of Virology},
year={2019},
month={Mar},
day={01},
volume={164},
number={3},
pages={927-941},
abstract={In October 2018, the order Bunyavirales was amended by inclusion of the family Arenaviridae, abolishment of three families, creation of three new families, 19 new genera, and 14 new species, and renaming of three genera and 22 species. This article presents the updated taxonomy of the order Bunyavirales as now accepted by the International Committee on Taxonomy of Viruses (ICTV).},
issn={1432-8798},
doi={10.1007/s00705-018-04127-3},
}

@article{Greener2020,
   title={SDSS-IV MaNGA: spatially resolved dust attenuation in spiral galaxies},
   volume={495},
   ISSN={1365-2966},
   url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/mnras/staa1300},
   DOI={10.1093/mnras/staa1300},
   number={2},
   journal={Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
   publisher={Oxford University Press (OUP)},
   author={Greener, Michael J and Aragón-Salamanca, Alfonso and Merrifield, Michael R and Peterken, Thomas G and Fraser-McKelvie, Amelia and Masters, Karen L and Krawczyk, Coleman M and Boardman, Nicholas F and Boquien, Médéric and Andrews, Brett H and et al.},
   year={2020},
   month={May},
   pages={2305–2320}
}

@article{Na2020,
   title={The deep Chandra survey in the SDSS J1030+0524 field},
   volume={637},
   ISSN={1432-0746},
   DOI={10.1051/0004-6361/202037914},
   journal={Astronomy \& Astrophysics},
   publisher={EDP Sciences},
   author={Nanni, R. and Gilli, R. and Vignali, C. and Mignoli, M. and Peca, A. and Marchesi, S. and Annunziatella, M. and Brusa, M. and Calura, F. and Cappelluti, N. and et al.},
   year={2020},
   month={May},
   pages={A52}
}

@article{M19,
   title={The SDSS-HET Survey of Kepler Eclipsing Binaries. Description of the Survey and First Results},
   volume={884},
   ISSN={1538-4357},
   DOI={10.3847/1538-4357/ab3793},
   number={2},
   journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
   publisher={American Astronomical Society},
   author={Mahadevan, Suvrath and Bender, Chad F. and Hambleton, Kelly and Fleming, Scott W. and Deshpande, Rohit and Conroy, Kyle and Matijevič, Gal and Hebb, Leslie and Roy, Arpita and Ak, Hasan and et al.},
   year={2019},
   month={Oct},
   pages={126}
}

@misc{green20,
    title={Spectroscopic and Photometric Periods of Six Ultracompact Accreting Binaries},
    author={Matthew J. Green and Thomas R. Marsh and Philip J. Carter and Danny Steeghs and Elmé Breedt and V. S. Dhillon and S. P. Littlefair and Steven G. Parsons and Paul Kerry and Nicola P. Gentile Fusillo and R. P. Ashley and Madelon C. P. Bours and Tim Cunningham and Martin J. Dyer and Boris T. Gänsicke and Paula Izquierdo and Anna F. Pala and Chuangwit Pattama and Sabrina Outmani and David I. Sahman and Boonchoo Sukaum and James Wild},
    year={2020},
    eprint={2005.12616},
    archivePrefix={arXiv},
    primaryClass={astro-ph.SR}
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for all your help but I still have a couple of problems!

Now the numbers are consistently on the right hand bottom on the first page of the chapters but all the subsequent pages, the number returns to centre bottom - same for the references too. Do you know how I can get all page numbers to be right hand bottom?

Comment: The bibliography name has changed which is great! Thank you :) I tried creating the new bib file but I've got a bit confused so now I have a couple more questions. I'm working in overleaf so I'm not sure how to compile pdflatex and bibtext (x2) and pdflatex (x2) - all I can do is recompile the pdf. Besides this, the error messages from before are still flagged for the same references... 

Also, if I'm creating my own bibtex file, will I have to add all new reference entries manually? I've been using Mendeley to import my references and will inevitably be adding more as I continue writing.

Comment: So a mixture of my original coding and your new coding has helped me get right hand bottom numbers on each page and the headers on every page except the first pages of the chapters and the references - so that is now fixed! :) just the problem of the super long reference remaining...

Comment: @Amelia I did not know that you were compiling using Overleaf. I have removed the compiling instruction from the answer. In Overleaf, with the two file (`.tex` code and `.bib` file) it  will autocompile.  I am able to compile the same `.tex` code in Overleaf [project](https://www.overleaf.com/3238186724vpqhzwmbqdkp) with no errors.

Comment: @Amelia You can save the imported References in Mendeley in a single `.bib` file.  See [this](https://blog.mendeley.com/2011/10/25/howto-use-mendeley-to-create-citations-using-latex-and-bibtex/).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :) It's all looking good now, just had to change my citations to the new version. The only problem left is that it seems to be suggesting the old citations as well and I don't know why because I deleted the old bib file... However, it's not a big problem, I just need to make sure I'm citing the correct file.